# P/Invoke passing struct longer than native code expects

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

If I have a native code that expects a structure with two fields:

```
[DllImport(LibraryName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int my_method(ref MyStruct myStruct);

// this is what native code expects
public struct MyStruct {
    IntPtr First;
    IntPtr Second;
}
```

but instead I pass another struct to it, will it work or not - by design or by accident?

```
[DllImport(LibraryName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int my_method(ref MyLongerStruct myLongerStruct);

// this is what I want to pass to it
public struct MyLongerStruct {
    IntPtr First;
    IntPtr Second;
    object ObjectPointer;
}
```

Will the object reference added to the end of the struct at C# side somehow affect P/Invoke call?

Comment: Of course it affects the pinvoke call, the marshaller will have to do more work.  A *lot* more work in this case since it is *object*, and that might very easily fail depending on what value you pass.  The native code is completely oblivious to it since it doesn't read the member.  Makes no sense at all to let it do the work or take the risk.

Comment: Thanks! I guess making `MyStruct` the first field of `MyLongerStruct` and passing only `MyStruct` is the perfect solution?

Comment: If the struct is embedded as a member in another struct then adding fields is a plain bug.  Since the struct member size is wrong, it affects the offset of all subsequent members.  This question is in high need of a "why on Earth am I doing this" explanation.

Comment: The question was for deeper understanding how marshaling works. I was going to add _unpinner field from [here](https://github.com/Spreads/Spreads/blob/master/src/Spreads.Extensions/Serialization/FixedBuffer.cs) to [here](https://github.com/Spreads/Spreads/blob/master/src/Spreads.Extensions/Serialization/DirectBuffer.cs) to keep a buffer pinned for the lifetime of DirectBuffer. But then completely redesigned the two structs to avoid weird things.

Answer (score 1):

I shouldn't work. And even more, you need to add and properly set StructLayoutAttribute to the structure, as it explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef4c3t39.aspx)

I think, the result should be like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct {
    IntPtr First;
    IntPtr Second;
}
```

Comment: Why it shouldn't work? (layout was assumed to be correct since it is in the context of P/Invoke). What if `object` was `IntPtr` instead?

Comment: The structure should have exact amount of members in the right order. StructLayout is to ensure the order, because compiler can reorder them and pass it in wrong order to the extern function.

Answer (score 1):

If the total difference in structure is fields added to the end, and you use `StructLayout` to prevent the compiler from optimizing the memory layout of your struct (as Alex Butenko suggests), then it's unlikely that there will be any negative side effects apart from a slight speed hit.

When you pass a managed `struct` to an external function via P/Invoke (using the `DllImport` attribute) there is a marshaling phase that converts your struct to a compatible format for the target.  For `ref` and `out` parameters the temporary is converted back when the invoked function returns, copying the values back to your `struct` instance.  All of this is abstracted away, although exactly how the marshaling is performed for each member can be tweaked with the right attributes.

This is how the .NET framework handles strings in P/Invoke.  Since it can't just send a `string` instance pointer to an API function that is expecting a `char *` (the two are nothing alike) there has to be some translation.

The fun part is that the marshaling code doesn't know anything about what the target is expecting other than what you tell it at the C# end, so if you are sending an extended version of the structure it will do the whole thing.  At the other end the native code will get a pointer to a memory block containing the information it's expecting, and it won't have any way to tell that there is more after the end of the structure.

Apart from that, no problem... as long as you're passing by reference and not by value.  Passing structs by value is something that should raise big red stop signs all over your brain.  Don't do it, it's evil.

Comment: Thanks! That was my thinking as well. I wonder if marshaling of the field `object ObjectPointer` always succeeds, or depends on the actual object type?